# Avoid clone duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm cloning table rows from one table to another using this:

```
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function(){
    var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
    clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
  })
```

I'd like to avoid cloning the same item more than once, so I tried something like this:

```
if(!$.contains("#items tbody",clone)){
  clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
}
```

but it keeps throwing `false`.

Has someone faced this problem?

Comment: [jQuery.contains](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/) It truly does help to first read the documentation. `$.contains` receives 2 DOM elements, not a selector string and a jQuery object.

Comment: Once the button is clicked, it should be disabled?

Comment: @Malk it is being removed. I just didn't paste that part to make it clearer.

Comment: How is it cloning more than once?

Comment: @Squint could you please help? I'm not very savvy at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `data-*` to a cloned row and check for that `data` later

```
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function(){

  var tr= $(this).closest('tr'); // the TR to clone

  if( tr.data("isCloned") === true) return; // Already cloned!! Stop here

  tr.data("isCloned", true);     // Remember I'm cloned yey!

  var clone = tr.clone(true);    // clone it
  clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
});
```

---

Another way using `.addClass()`:

```
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function(){

  var tr = $(this).closest('tr:not(".isCloned")'); // the TR to clone?

  tr.addClass("isCloned");       // Remember I'm cloned yey!

  var clone = tr.clone(true);    // clone it
  clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
});
```

the last example might not be obvious but if the selector returns nothing (thanks to the `:not()` selector) than nothing will be cloned and appended.

Comment: cool solution, +1, but if a duplicate row already exists in the destination table this obviously won't do anything to prevent the dupe.

Comment: @Pamblam interesting thinking. Let's see what OP has to comment on that.

Comment: Actually the table with the clones always starts empty. Script didn't work here (1st example).

Comment: 2nd example did work but I'm curious if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Onilol I'm not sure at which point you don't want the TR do be cloned any more... so I'm guess-gaming here ;) You can always remove that button from the cloned element

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the button you cannot add the row again.

```js
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function(){
    this.disabled = true;
    var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
    //clone.find("button").remove();
    clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
  })
```

```css
table { width:40%; height:140px; display:inline-block;  border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<table id="source">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><button type='button' name='addItem'>+<td>1<td>one
    <tr><td><button type='button' name='addItem'>+<td>2<td>two
    <tr><td><button type='button' name='addItem'>+<td>3<td>three
    <tr><td><button type='button' name='addItem'>+<td>4<td>four
    <tr><td><button type='button' name='addItem'>+<td>5<td>five
</table>

<table id="items"><tbody>
  
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```